# Link to nodes in WYSIWYG Editor and Domain Access

Tags: nodes, domain-access, navigation

I  have a Drupal installation using Domain Access.
Is there a solution for inserting links on nodes using WYSIWYG-Editor considering if the node is published to the particular domain.
For Example:

Node A, published to domain Y and Z, has a link to node B, published only to domain Z.
Viewing node A on domain Z the link is rendered as a link. Viewing node A on domain Y the link is rendered as plain text (without

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the [WYSIWYG](http://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module or [CKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) or the like?  Which WYSIWIYG editor are you using if you are using the former?

Comment: I'm using WYSIWYG with TinyMCE

Answer (score 2):

See the [LinkIt project](http://drupal.org/project/linkit).

Its flexible API should let you hook into the node listing logic it uses to inject SQL to group node listing by Domain. You should be able to make a plugin with it ... I see no existing solution off-hand (I've used LinkIt and DomainAccess, but not had users linking around sub-domains from the WYSIWYG. My domains were very separate from one another).